# What happens to those who were inside during the fidelius and they step outside? Are they under the fidelius, too?

Tags: harry-potter

When the Fidelius Charm is cast on a home, are the occupants/ domicile also affected by the spell? What happens when they step outside the home?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the “Secret Information” is. Although, Fidelius Charm has primarily been used to hide locations in the canon (that’s why it’s confusing), it could be used to conceal any information.

From official [Wizarding World](https://www.wizardingworld.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/secret-keeper):

> The Fidelius Charm is extremely ancient and still used to this day. It involves the concealment of information inside a living person. The chosen person, or Secret Keeper, is the only person who is thenceforth capable of revealing the protected information to others, however many previously knew it.

It means that if the secret information is only about location of a place, the occupants won’t go invisible. If the secret information is about existence of a person, that person would go invisible (although we never saw such instances in the canon; I wonder why they didn’t use this; Hiding information of Potters’ existence would have been way more effective).

Comment: Imagine Voldemort being like "Potter who?"

Comment: Imagine sitting in the Three Broomsticks pub and getting not even one drop of tasty Butterbeer, because Madame Rosmerta is not in the know ...

Comment: There is in fact a fanfic where Harry uses Fidelius to hide himself: https://www.fanfiction.net/s/8257400/1/Harry-Potter-and-the-Power-of-Paranoia

Answer (score 1):

The occupants inside a home are affected by the spell, the best example is in Deathly Hallows with the taboo of the name of Voldemort, Death Eaters know that somebody are speaking the name of Voldemort but they cannot locate the people.

Outside of the home the only thing people are affected is that they cannot divulge the secret.